# IE forcing scrollbars on iframes unless domain is trusted

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I have a web page made up of multiple iframes. These iframes are all sourced from the same domain and it's the same domain as the top level page.

In Internet Explorer it is showing scrollbars for every iframe and I can only make them disappear by adding the url to the 'trusted sites' in IE security settings.

Is there a way to do this so IE does not require trust of my site, because I find it odd given everything is from the same domain.

Note: 
overflow: hidden
scrolling="no"

does nothing, this seems to be a 'trusted site' thing.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing  it with !important ?

Comment: The actual iframes are rendered by the server via GWT so I'll have to see if it has an ID to override this as I do not have access to this code. However, I presume the issue is more to do with IE forcing this on the user until it is added to 'Trusted Sites', i.e. is this an IE issue that cannot be fixed by CSS?

Comment: Try adding the `scrolling="false"` attribute to the iframes.

Comment: No. As I said, this appears to be a 'trusted site' thing within Internet Explorer

Comment: Could be quirks mode or compatibility mode as well. I’d start by checking if the code you output makes IE go into one of these modes.